# Disable pretty writing of strings to file

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I can use `shell:strings(false)` to disable the pretty writing of strings in shell.

I am saving a list of integers to file and need the numbers, not string. eg.

```
[[8,1,3,100,35,25,10,20,25],"+\v%"],
```

should have `[57,63,11]` at the end instead.

```
63> "9?\v".
[57,63,11]
```

How do I change this?

```
generate(Num) -> 
  Result = generate(Num, []),
  Dedup = deduplicated(Result),
  file:write_file("./react/src/Data/gennedmons", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Dedup])),
  Dedup.
```

I have tried writin with ~w, too. No apparent effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~w` seems to do what you want in this simple test. Does this not match what you're doing?

```
1> file:write_file("foo", io_lib:fwrite("~p~n", ["9?\v"])).
ok
2>
[2]+  Stopped                 erl
~ $ cat foo
"9?\v"
~ $ fg
erl

2> file:write_file("foo", io_lib:fwrite("~w~n", ["9?\v"])).
ok
3>
[2]+  Stopped                 erl
~ $ cat foo
[57,63,11]
~ $
```

Comment: It does, thank you. I had put `~w` in the wrong module and had a different module overwrite that was still using ~p.

Comment: You will save few CPU cycles using directly simple `file:write_file("foo", io_lib:write("9?\v")).`